# What is aptitude's extended state information

Tags: apt, aptitude

I have both **apt-get** and **aptitude** installed on my system. When I am performing any operation using **aptitude**, I see `Reading extended state information` and `Writing extended state information`. These messages are not present with **apt-get**. What state information is aptitude reading that apt-get is not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the extended state information is stored in `/var/lib/apt/extended_states`.  Looking at the file on my machine, it stores the architecture for each installed package and whether or not those packages were installed manually or automatically (i.e. as a dependency of another package).

Answer (score 1):

Manual page of `apt-mark` (that is a command included in apt package) tells in FILES section:

> ```
>     /var/lib/apt/extended_states
>        Status list of auto-installed packages. Configuration Item: Dir::State::extended_states.
> ```

`apt-mark` and `apt-get` may modify the file. I don't know, if `aptitude` uses exactly the same file to keep account of automatically installed package. If there exits a record for a package in the file with line

```
Auto-Installed: 1
```

then the package is automatically installed. Otherwise it is manually installed.